# ¿Hay alguna política en específico para los nombres de usuario en Stackoverflow?

Tags: discusión

Quiero saber si hay alguna política para los nombres de usuarios en Stackoverflow, ya que he visto algunos nombres de usuarios muy extraños.

El último era uno que decidió llamarse *Informático Cabreado*. Hay un saludo muy cortés de uno de los moderadores, dándole la bienvenida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A mi particularmente se me hace difícil saludar así. O, supongamos que alguno decida llamarse *Don Nadie*... si quieres mencionarlo en algún comentario tendrás que referirte a él como tal.

**¿Existe una política sobre nombres de usuarios?**

**¿Se podría sugerir a esos usuarios un cambio de nombre?**

Comment: Perdonadme las erratas, no sabía que saldría en meta :P

Comment: En la red de Stack Exchange no hay una política de nombres definida; Simplemente se pide que los nombres y los avatares no sean ofensivos (y "aptos para niños" o PG). Y si aplicasen algunas reglas, serían las que se describen en [Compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) en el centro de ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué significa Cabreado en España? No veo lo grave de la situacón

Comment: Para mí es todo lo contrario, "cabreado" es una forma bastante respetuosa, yo hubiese usado algo mucho peor para referirme a lo mismo.. es un buen nick.

Comment: @ReneLimon en España se usa en sentido de alguien que está enfadado o de mal humor, [ver varias acepciones](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6SOVjNv) según la RAE.

Answer (score 6):

He encontrado tres publicaciones en inglés sobre temas de nombres de usuarios:

- [What are the rules governing display names and avatars?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/what-are-the-rules-governing-display-names-and-avatars)

  Esta trata principalmente sobre nombres falsos en cuanto a identidad, no a nombres ofensivos.
- [Why are we allowing usernames such as “stackoverflow”, “stack overflow” and “moderator”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280033/3045491)
  En esta se trata el tema de nombres *reservados*  como pudiera ser "Comunidad" o "StackOverflow" pero tambien tiene una respuesta que dice que los moderadores podemos revertir un nombre de usuario al incial, `userxxxxxx`.
- [How much leeway do we give possibly offensive usernames?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202420/how-much-leeway-do-we-give-possibly-offensive-usernames)

  Esta otra pregunta si trata sobre un nombre que pueda ser ofensivo: "Assh O. Le" -> La proncunciación sería como un insulto en inglés.

  El comentario con más votos sugiere que "¿qué sucede si es su nombre real?" (y es lo que el usuario afirma).

En la sala de moderadores, (donde me ayudaron a encontrar estos enlaces) me dijeron que no conocen de politicas en cuanto a nombres de usuarios pero que su sistema a proceder seria el mismo que en la situación de una publicación/comentario offensivo.

Yo personalmente me comunicaría con ese hipotético usuario para que por favor eligiera otro o se le pondría el inicial.

El problema será en algunos casos discernir qué es ofensivo. Puede ser totalmente subjetivo.

---

En cuando a **Informático cabreado** no le veo nada de malo. Al menos lo que yo puedo entender por cabreo.

Comment: Al final decís "*me comunicaría con ese usuario*". Creo que se confunde si te referís a un usuario X con un nombre ofensivo, o en particular a "Informático Cabreado" (espero que sea lo primero, porque no le veo nada mal a ese usuario cabreado)

Comment: @Mariano sisi, por supuesto que sería en el hipotético de un nombre rudo. Informático cabreado no lo veo mal... Todo nos hemos cabreado cuando algo no compila. Quizá llegue un usuario luego llamado Informático Sorprendido xD

Comment: Recuerdo que alguna vez vi un nombre de usuario que decía CTM, que para los chilenos y creo que argentinos se puede interpretar de una forma muy ofensiva

Comment: @Flxtr eso podrían ser siglas de lo que sea...

Answer (score 4):

En mi opinión,no es que *Informático Cabreado* sea un username especialmente grave. Yo personalmente creo que en ningún caso se debe imponer una política excesivamente restrictiva en cuanto al particular.

Si estaría a favor de restringir nombres que sea ofensivos por cuestiones de religión,raza, etc... o que en general sean palabras claramente malsonantes. *Cabreado* no entra en mi definición de "claramente malsonante", por eso me parece que debemos en todo caso ser lo menos restrictivos posible, solo lo mínimo indispensable para no ofender susceptibilidades.